# How can I determine the correct data type and length range for transforming Excel datasets into IBM DB2 Cloud tables using R?

Tags: types, range

am bigenner in R and sql , i have to work on project that can be connect between IBM db2 and R to do queries on it. Create tables on the IBM cloud then shift all existed csv datasets into these tables. The creation was done successfully but i was struggled with data transforming.  my question is how can i know the correct data type and length range for the columns to transform the data correctly?  thank you

i try to transform data from excel datasets into created tables on IBM cloud